# Continuity from a topology to itself

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Consider the function $f:(\mathbb{R},T)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},T)$ such that $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $T=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(-\infty,x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Prove that $f$ if not continuous at $a>0$.

OK first of all I do not get where the '$a$' comes from. Anyways, can anyone help me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How do you define continuity at a point?

Comment: I guess you need to prove it is not continuous at any point $a>0$.

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos Isn't there only one definition here?

Comment: @Mark No. There are several definitions.

Comment: @Mark There are more than one, but fortunately they are all equivalent. It is a good thing to know which one is practicized by the OP.

Comment: @drhab Well, the one I always used is that for each open neighborhood $V$ of $f(a)$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $a$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$. I believe OP should know this definition.

Comment: that's the general topological definition. considering $\mathbb{R}$ is a metric space, there are other definitions that are equivalent to the one you cited.

Comment: @Zest $\mathbb{R}$ in **this** topology is *not* a metric space. So no $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definitions as for metric spaces apply.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b\in \Bbb R^+.$ Then $a\in (-\infty, a+b)\in T.$ If $f$ were continuous at $a$ then for some $t\in T$  we would have $a\in t$ and $\{f(x):x\in t\} \subset (-\infty,a+b).$

But if $a\in t\in T$ then for some $c\in \Bbb R^+$ we have $t\supset (\infty,a+c)\supset (-\infty,0)$ so $$\{f(x):x\in t\}\supset \{f(x):x<0\}=\{x^2:x<0\}=\Bbb R^+\not \subset (-\infty,a+b).$$